# Big O Notation - How do you describe a 2D array of different lengths?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I'm having trouble understanding what the Big O notation would be for nested data structures like 2D arrays or an object of arrays.

#### The Scenario

Sum all of the values in all of the arrays.

#### What I know

For example, my understanding is the below data structure would be `O(n^2)` since both dimensions are the same length (3x3).

```js
// O(n^2)

const arr = [
  [1,2,3],
  [1,2,3],
  [1,2,3],
]
```

This would be `O(n * m)` where `n` is the length of the first dimension (2), and `m` is the length of the second dimension (3).

```js
// O(n * m)

const arr = [
  [1,2,3],
  [1,2,3],
]
```

#### What I don't know

But what about a data structure where the second dimension arrays are different lengths?

```js
// Maybe O(n * m)?

const arr = [
  [1,2,3],
  [1,2,3,4,5,6],
  [1,2]
]

let sum = 0

for (let nums of arr) {
  for (let num of nums) {
    arrSum += num
  }
}

// sum = 30
```

Or an object where the values are arrays?

```js
// Maybe O(n * m)?

const obj = {
  a: [1,2,3],
  b: [1,2,3,4,5,6],
  c: [1,2]
}

let sum = 0

for (let nums of Object.values(obj)) {
  for (let num of nums) {
    sum += num
  }
}

// sum = 30
```

I am getting stumped on how this would be represented in Big O notation. My thought is you would still go with `O(n * m)` where `n` is the length of the first dimension (or the number keys), and `m` represents the longest array in the second dimension (or key value).

Am I thinking about this correctly?

Comment: "m represents the longest array in the second dimension" sounds about right

Comment: "*My thought is you would still go with O(n * m) where n is the length of the first dimension (or the number keys), and m represents the longest array in the second dimension (or key value).*" seems correct. Remember that big-O doesn't measure things concretely, it's there to show you the growth trend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to make this more complicated than it is. `n` and `m` are both simply variables. What they describe is entirely up to you. Actually a proper choice for what you base the runtime-complexity of your algorithm on can be of considerable importance.

So for the case of an array of arrays with different lengths, you can simply pick `n` as the sum of the length of all "inner" arrays. For the case with the object, the problem can be reduced to the first problem. Minor nitpick: you depend on the internal behavior of `Object.values`; I've simply assumed it's in `O(n)`.

So in general: pick the most accurate description of the problem-**size**, not the structure. Whether you're summing all elements of an `256 x 256` or an `2 x 32768` array won't make any difference in terms of runtime-complexity.

Comment: This is the right way of thinking about it, for sure. By the way, `Object.values` returns a fresh array each time, so it can't be faster than linear time in the number of properties. (This doesn't change the time complexity of the OP's code, because it only calls `Object.values` once, and that isn't the dominant term.)

Comment: @kaya3 well, actually it's pseudocode, so we can't know for sure. If we assume `Object.values` operates on the same basis as the implementation in javascript you're right. But since it's pseudocode unfortunately one can only guess about the internals without a clean specification. Definitely an important discussion to have in order to properly determine the runtime though

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in terms of complexity, both examples are in `O(n * m)`. But, sometimes you need a tighter time complexity. In your case, if we suppose that the length of arrays are `m_1, m_2, ..., m_n`, you can say the time complexity is in `Theta(sum_{i = 1}^{n} m_i)`. In this case, you can simplify it, based on existing situations. For example, sometimes, the sum of lengths is equal to a constant factor `n`, e.g., `2n`. In this case, the time complexity will be `O(n)` or even tighter `Theta(n)`.